# Динамический фильтр, склейка запроса из $_GET

Tags: php

Имеется массив, который я получаю с ссылки вида site.com/?cpu=1,2&brand=2,3&ram=2,3 методом $_GET

```
array(3) {
  ["cpu"]=>
  string(3) "1,2"
  ["brand"]=>
  string(3) "2,3"
  ["ram"]=>
  string(3) "2,3"
}
```

Как мне из данного массива склеить запрос следующего содержания?
P.S Возможно имею неправильное видение составления запроса, если где то ошибся логикой запроса просьба поправить.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE slug = cpu AND name = 1 OR slug = cpu AND name = 2
WHERE slug = brand AND name = 2 OR slug = brand AND name = 3
WHERE slug = ram AND name = 2 OR slug = ram AND name = 3
```

Пытался как-то сделать вот так, но видимо имею неправильное представление о реализации.

```
  foreach($request->all() as $name => $value) {
            $valuesArray = explode(',', $value);
            foreach($valuesArray as $row) {
                $sql[] = 'WHERE ' . $name . '=' . $row;
            }
        }
```

P.S Делаю динамический фильтр, который выдает найденные позиции запрос у которого генерируется через $_GET

Comment: структуру таблицы покажите

Comment: Дело в том, что еще нет конечно понимания, как правильно должны выглядеть таблицы и их связи, пытаюсь реализовать пока что так:

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3D8WvtT

Comment: К примеру в Я.Маркете данные берутся из $_GET и они уже подставляются и формируется запрос, тут хочется реализовать нечто подобное.

Comment: Google по запросу динамический фильтр выдает инфу по EAV, возможно это то, что хочется получить в итоге.

Comment: В яндексе вообще не php используется, если уж на то пошло. И далеко не факт, что запрос у них формируется именно так. В общем, сначала надо четко понять задачу, потом под эту задачу спроектировать БД, а уже третьим этапом заниматься формированием запросов к ним.

Answer (score 1):

Если для лаборатной, то так:

```
$parts = [];
foreach ($request->all() as $name => $value) {
    $parts[] = "(slug = '$name' AND name in ($value))";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $parts);
```

Но в промышленном коде, естественно, такое нельзя использовать ни за что. Необходимо добавить очень тщательную проверку входящих данных: проверку существования полей, проверку формата полей, экранизацию входных данных для SQL, учесть случай когда нет ни одного фильтра, добавить пагинацию если данных очень много.

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь избегать составление SQL-запроса путем склейки условий из пришедших данных. Это даже не выстрел в ногу, а бросок туда гранаты. В лучшем случае получите просто неконсистентный SQL,  а в худшем - кул-хацкера, прочитавшего, что такое SQL-инъекция.

Попытаюсь протелепатить, что в случае с ram у вас передаются числа минимального и максимального значения, база mysql(для других баз будут просто другие операторы)

```
function fields($field, $count){
    $out = array();
    for($i = 0;$i < $count; $++) $out[] = $field.'=?';
    return implode(' OR ', $out); 
}

function binds($type, $count){
    $out = '';
    for($i = 0;$i < $count; $++) $out .= $type;
    return $out; 
}

$db = new mysqli(данные для коннекта);

$ramMin = isset($_GET['ram'])?$_GET['ram']:PHP_INT_MIN;
$ramMax = isset($_GET['ram'])?$_GET['ram']:PHP_INT_MAX;

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ram>=? AND ram<=?";
$params = array($ramMin, $ramMax);
$bind = "ii";

if(isset($_GET['brand']){
    $params = array_merge($params, explode(',',$_GET['brand']));
    $SQL .= ' AND ('.fields('brand', count($brandArray)).')';
    $bind .= binds('s', count($brandArray));
}
//аналогично для cpu

$finalParams = array();
foreach($params as $param) $finalParams = &$param;

$stmt = $db->prepare($SQL);

call_user_func_array(
    array($stmt, 'bind_param'), 
    array_merge(array($bind), $finalParams)
    );
$stmt->execute();
```